# CRUD with advanced (column) filtering?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid, crud

I have spent weeks trying to build a CRUD with advanced (column) filtering features, like this one:

[image]

Do you know any CRUD software which can deal (server-side processing) with a 2000 records database?

I have tried Grocery CRUD, i loved its [Datatables theme](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_theme), but it doesn't support server-side processing (it's not implemented into Grocery CRUD)

I am currently trying JqGrid, do you think that could be a good solution?

Comment: Most of the datatables you find won't come with CRUD built-in, but they generally will be extensible enough to implement it yourself.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645768/which-php-framework-has-the-most-advanced-crud-generator?rq=1) might help - Personally, I would use an ORM

Comment: Don't you think ORM sounds more complex? I just need a CRUD table with column filters. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like:
http://propelorm.org/

Comment: There are demos with the download.

Comment: Didn't find any demo yet, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the scenario using jqGrid. To fill the grid and to filter the data you have two options: the first will be implementing paging, sorting and filtering on *the server side* and the second will be loading all 2000 records database on the client side and usage client side filtering, sorting and paging. For the last scenario you need just add `loadonce: true` option to jqGrid. The server method specified by `url` need return *all* records (2000 records database). The option `rowNum` specified the number of rows which you shows the user on one page. You should use `toppager: true` or the option `pager` (as `pager: "#pagerId"`) to add pager at the top, at the bottom or at the both parts of the grid. To add editing buttons in every row of the grid you can add the column having [formatter: "actions"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). To add the toolbar for filtering you should use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention) method. [The official demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) of jqGrid provide some examples of usage of all the above methods. Stackoverflow contains many other examples. `formatter: "actions"` can be used either for [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) of for [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing). In both cases the results of editing will be sent to `editurl`. So you can successfully implement CRUD scenario with server-side processing.

Comment: thank you @Oleg for your detailed reply, I appreciate. anyway I think server-side processing should be chosen, for speed issues.

Comment: I would also like to be able to add new entries

Comment: @JessStone: The are many options how you can implement this. You can for example use `navGrid` and [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) to add "Add" button to the pager. Alternatively you can place any custom button somewhere new the page and call [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) or [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to add new row to the grid.

Comment: NB: I am working with PHP/MySQL: will these methods update the MySQL table records?

Comment: @JessStone: I don't use PHP or MySQL, but you would find some demos on [the trirand site](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5). In general `name` property in `colModel` of the columns with `editable: true` property and `id` property with rowid and `oper` with the  value `add`, `edit` or `del` will be sent to the server. So you can implement CRUD scenario with any server side.